# Use SUM value of the highest months

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum, partition

We need to get numbers for 3 months, One Year, Three Years and Five Years.
The below query will return 0 for OneY, ThreeY and FiveY if the oldest period_end_date is less than 12 months.
How can I change the query so that it includes the numbers within the one year, three year, five year ?
For OneY if the the number of months the entity existed is less than 12 months, then assign the SUM of rt for maximum months the entity exist.

Say the entity existed for 3 months:

So, for OneY assign the SUM of rt for the 3 months

For ThreeY assign the SUM of rt for the 3 months

For FiveY assign the SUM of rt for the 3 months

Sample data:

```
Entity_id  Period_end_Date  One_Month_value
123        11/30/20         10
123        10/31/20         20
```

Current result with the below query:

```
ThreeM: 30
OneY: 0
ThreeY: 0
FiveY: 0
```

Expected result

```
ThreeM: 30
OneY: 30
ThreeY: 30
FiveY: 30
```

Thank you.

```
         SELECT SUM (DECODE (rnk, 2, rt, 0)) as ThreeM,
            SUM (DECODE (rnk, 11, rt, 0)) as OneY,
            SUM (DECODE (rnk, 35, rt, 0)) as ThreeY,
            SUM (DECODE (rnk, 59, rt, 0)) as FiveY,
       FROM (SELECT entity_id,
                    rnk,
                    SUM (one_month)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY rnk)
                       rt
               FROM (  SELECT psm.One_Month_Value,
                              RANK ()
                              OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id)
                                    ORDER BY period_end_date DESC)
                                 AS rnk
                         FROM myTbl psm
                        WHERE     TRIM (psm.entity_id) = 123
                              AND period_end_date < '12/31/2020'
                     ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) rank_tab
              WHERE rnk < 60)
      WHERE rnk IN (1,2,11,35,59);
```

Comment: Please build a db fiddle with enough sample data so that we can test a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, I added sample data, current result and expected result. Thank you !

Comment: Two entire rows of sample data?

Comment: @faujong Please do not post answers in an edit to the question; if you want to self-answer a question then post the answer as an answer. I am going to rollback your question and you can post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Entity_id,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN period_end_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ), -3 )
         THEN One_Month_Value
         END
       ) AS ThreeM,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN period_end_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -12 )
         THEN One_Month_Value
         END
       ) AS OneY,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN period_end_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -36 )
         THEN One_Month_Value
         END
       ) AS ThreeY,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN period_end_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -60 )
         THEN One_Month_Value
         END
       ) AS FiveY
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Period_End_Date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -60 ) 
GROUP BY
       Entity_ID
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Entity_id, Period_end_Date, One_Month_value ) AS
SELECT 123, DATE '2020-11-30', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, DATE '2020-10-31', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2021-01-31', -LEVEL ), LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 72;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ENTITY_ID | THREEM | ONEY | THREEY | FIVEY
> --------: | -----: | ---: | -----: | ----:
>       123 |     30 |   30 |     30 |    30
>         1 |      6 |   78 |    666 |  1830
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b69434af91373c77e3003ede72341510)*